# Maintaining dataframe shape when slicing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've imported a .csv into pandas and want to extract specific values and put them into a new column whilst maintaining the existing shape.

So `df[::3]` extracts the data-

```
1 1    
2 4  
3 7  
4  
5  
6  
7
```

I want it to look like

```
1 1  
2  
3  
4 4  
5  
6  
7 7
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Read the guideline for posting questions. As a rule of thumb, you should post your own attempt at solving the issue. In other words, this community is not aimed at solving problems without any own efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:/users/k_sego/colsplit.csv",sep=";")
df1 = df[['col1']]
df2 = df[['col2']]
DF = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer',left_on=['col1'],right_on=['col2'])
```

and the result is

```
    col1  col2
0    1.0   1.0
1    2.0   NaN
2    3.0   NaN
3    4.0   4.0
4    5.0   NaN
5    6.0   NaN
6    7.0   7.0
7    NaN   NaN
8    NaN   NaN
9    NaN   NaN
10   NaN   NaN
```